# Failure of producing a histogram in R if using breaks=a numeric vector

Tags: r, vector, histogram

Is there any difference between using `breaks=c(1,2,3,4,5)` and `breaks=c(1:5)`?

I am using `hist(...)` function to get a histogram for a dataset. 
If I use `hist(MyDataFile$V3, breaks=c(1,2,3,4,5))`, then I get the correct histogram.

If I use `hist(MyDataFile$V3, breaks=c(1:5))` or 
`hist(MyDataFile$V3, breaks=seq(1,5,1))`, then the histogram does not show correct rectangles, and it only gives me a lot of vertical parallel lines at some breaks instead, but not the correct histogram.

I cannot figure out what is wrong with my the value of my `breaks`.

[UPDATA] It is a silly mistake. The problem is solved if set `freq=FALSE`. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: If you are using `1:5` no need to wrap it with `c(..)`  Regarding the difference, one should be numeric class and 1:5 integer class.  Based on a reproducible example I tried, I am not getting the output you referred.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I replace c(1:5) with 1:5, but the same problem still exists.

Comment: I meant that 1:5 doesn't need a wrapper with `c`, but it is an integer.  check `class(1:5)` and `class(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))`.  Please show a reproducible example that shows your problem

Comment: @akrun This is what I am using 
`MyMin <- -0.5
MyMax <- 5.5
xbreaks1 <- MyMin:MyMax
xbreaks2 <- c(-0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5)`
`hist(MyDataFile$V1, breaks = xbreaks2) # This works great.`
`hist(MyDataFile$V1, breaks = xbreaks1) # This does not work`

Comment: We can't reproduce it without knowing `MyDataFile$V1`  Also, the `xbreaks2` is not what you said in the post i.e. `c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`

Comment: @akrun Sorry for my bad editing style. MyDataFile$V1 is integer values between 0 and 5.

Comment: @akrun I am sorry. At first, I wanted to make it easy in my question. So I used integers in my question.

Comment: Sorry, i can't reproduce it with `set.seed(24);
 v1 <- sample(1:5, 30, replace = TRUE);  hist(v1, breaks = xbreaks1);hist(v1, breaks = xbreaks2)`

Comment: @akrun Is it possibly because my data file is a txt file?

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the data in your post. i.e. `dput(MyDataFile$V1)` if it is a large dataset, use only 100 or so observations, i.e. `dput(head(MyDataFIle$V1, 100))`

Comment: @akrun 
I am trying to clear my code and post it here. However, now xbreaks1 does not work, either. The following is all the code:
    `MyDataFile <- read.table("MyDataFile.txt");`     

`max1 <- max(MyDataFile$V8)+0.5`  

`min1 <- min(MyDataFile$V8)-0.5`  

`xbreaks1 <- min1:max1`  
'xbreaks2 <- c(-0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5,  4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10.5, 11.5, 12.5, 13.5, 14.5, 15.5, 16.5, 17.5, 18.5)`  
`png("histogram.png")`  
`hist(MyDataFile$V8, main=NULL, breaks = xbreaks2, 
     xlab="The Number of LAG within the vicinity of TCR", ylim=c(0,Upbound))`
`dev.off() `

Comment: Sorry to say this.  I can't reproduce your code without the `MyDataFile$V8`.

Comment: @akrun Thank you so much for your time. I This is the data:
`c(11L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 8L, 3L, 10L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
11L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 12L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 
1L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 10L, 6L, 12L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 5L, 10L, 2L, 4L, 18L, 9L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 11L, 7L, 12L, 3L, 1L, 
11L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 5L, 12L, 
3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 11L, 0L, 3L, 6L, 
10L, 2L, 11L, 3L, 9L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 5L)`

Comment: Tried with your new data, it is giving me similar histogram for both `xbreaks1` and `xbreaks2`

Comment: @akrun I got only vertical lines in my histogram, instead of the correct figure.
Did you get online vertical lines, too?

Comment: For me, I am getting bars for the both cases using your data.

Comment: @akrun What is the possible reason for it? I am so confused.

Comment: @S. Liu if you took the time to actually post your full code, data, and whole work flow it would be much easier.

Comment: @akrun and @Cyrus Mohammadian and another friend who I did not remember your name. I found the problem. How silly. In some situation, the default value of `freq` is `FALSE`; in other situations, the default value is `TRUE`. The problem is solved if I set `freq = FALSE`.   Thank you for your time. I greatly appreciate it. :)